# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm getting a Json response from Flickr api which is like :

```
{
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1,
    "perpage": 100,
    "total": 2,
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "14774811932",
        "owner": "32738276@N08",
        "secret": "cbb99f0039",
        "server": "3853",
        "farm": 4,
        "title": "Weltschmerz",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0,
        "date_faved": "1432471819"
      },
      {
        "id": "13274800365",
        "owner": "114920113@N07",
        "secret": "b652859e6a",
        "server": "3688",
        "farm": 4,
        "title": "cactus desert",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0,
        "date_faved": "1432466782"
      }
    ]
  },
  "stat": "ok"
}
```

and I need to get the two `Photo` objects in an ArrayList.

My code is:

```
Helper helper = new Helper(this);
    String jsonString = helper.loadJSONFromAsset();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Photos photos = gson.fromJson(jsonString,
                new TypeToken<Photos>() { }.getType());
   // ArrayList<Photo> photos = gson.fromJson(jsonString,
   //             new TypeToken<ArrayList<Photo>>(){}.getType());
```

Currently I load the file from assets. When this works I'll change it to the flickr api

Photo class :

```
public class Photos {
    Integer page;
    Integer pages;
    Integer perpage;
    Integer total;
    ArrayList<Photo> photos;
    String stat;


//getters and setters here
```

My understanding is that I have first to extract the `photos` item and then from that item to extract the Array `photo` so I can get the ArrayList I need.

Comment: What does your Photo class look like?

Comment: @BidhanA just updated the answer with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had to create the Gson TypeToken like this:

```
public class Photos {
   Integer page;
   Integer pages;
   Integer perpage;
   Integer total;
   ArrayList<Photo> photo;
   String stat;

   //setters and getters

}
```

In this way you could replicate the Flickr JSON and Gson will map the Json correctly with:

```
 Photos photos = gson.fromJson(jsonString,
            new TypeToken<Photos>(){}.getType());
```

then you can get your photos ArrayList with:

```
 photos.getPhoto();
```

Comment: Try to take another step back. Create a FlickrResponse class which does contain a Photos property

Comment: hmmm...interesting. I'll check it asap.

Comment: works for FlickrResponse. But how am I going to get Photos now from FlickrResponse? I can't apply fromJson method on FlickrResponse result.

Comment: With the getters both in FlickrResponse class and Photos class you can obtain the photos ArrayList<Photo>. Gson do the mapping work for you